# In the React.js context element is reset on every redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

When you log in, there is no problem on the page entered with the first redirect. According to the console logs, the context is full. However, when you click on any page using the "Navbar", the data received with the context returns null, and you are redirected to the Login page. I do not provide any method that will reset the data in the context. But I don't understand why it resets.

Not: For session control, the isEnable variable in the context is checked.

index.js =>

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <UserProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </UserProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

app.js =>

```
function App() {
  const { contextUser } = useContext(UserContext);



  const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      background: {
        default: '#gray', // Background color of the app
      },
    },
  });
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar/>{/* Router in the Navbar */}
      <Routes>
        {contextUser.isEnable? (
          <>
            <Route path={"/"} element={<PatientQuery key={10}/>}/> 
            <Route path={"/Rapor_Sorgulama"} element={<PatientQuery key={10}/>}/>
            <Route path={"/Hasta_Listesi"} element={<PatientList key={11}/>}/>
            <Route path={"/Rapor_Tanımlama"} element={<ReportDefine key={12}/>}/>
            <Route path={"/Tüm_Raporlar"} element={<AllReports key={13}/>}/>
            <Route path="/MASTER" element={<Master/>} />
            <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage/>} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Route path={"/"} element={<PatientQuery key={10}/>}/> 
            <Route path="/Rapor_Sorgulama" element={<PatientQuery key={1}/>} />
            <Route path="/Hasta_Listesi" element={<Login key={2}/>} />
            <Route path="/Rapor_Tanımlama" element={<Login  key={3}/>}/>
            <Route path="/Tüm_Raporlar" element={<Login  key={4}/>}/>
            <Route path="/Login" element={<Login  key={5}/>}/>
            <Route path="/SignUp" element={<SignUp  key={6}/>}/>
            <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage  key={7}/>}/>
            {/* <Navigate to="/error" /> */}
          </>
        )}

        {/*
          my_pages.map((page,index) => (
            <Route path={`/${page}`} element={components[index]}/>
          ))
          */}
      </Routes>
      
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

context/Context.js =>

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

// User Authentication Context
export const UserContext = createContext();

export function UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [contextUser, setContextUser] = useState({
    fullName: "",
    email: "",
    token: "",
    image: null,
    authorities: [],
    isEnable: null
  });

  const logIn = (userData) => {
    setContextUser({
      fullName: userData.user.fullName,
      email: userData.user.email,
      token: userData.token,
      image: null,
      authorities: userData.user.authorities,
      isEnable: true
    });
    logContext()
  };
  
  const logContext = function () {
    console.log(contextUser)
  };

  const logOut = () => {
    setContextUser({
      fullName: "deleted",
      email: "",
      token: "",
      image: null,
      authorities: [""],
      isEnable: false
    });
  };
  

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ contextUser, logIn, logContext }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Navbar.js =>

```
export default function Navbar() {
  const my_pages = ['Rapor_Sorgulama', 'Hasta_Listesi', 'Rapor_Tanımlama', 'Tüm_Raporlar'];
  const components = [
    <PatientQuery key={my_pages[0]}></PatientQuery>,
    <PatientList key={my_pages[1]}></PatientList>,
    <ReportDefine key={my_pages[2]}></ReportDefine>,
    <AllReports key={my_pages[3]}></AllReports>,
    <Login key={5}></Login>,
    <SignUp key={6}></SignUp>,
  ];

  const { contextUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  console.log("contextUser: ")
  console.log(contextUser)

  const my_settings = ['Profil', 'Hesap', 'Çıkış'];

  const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = useState(null);
  

  const handleOpenSettingsMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleCloseSettingsMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElUser(null);
  };

  const myTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: 'dark',
      primary: {
        main: '#002092',
      }, secondary: {
        main: '#002092',
      },
    },
  });

  return (
    <>
      <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
        <AppBar position="static" style={{ backgroundColor: '#002090' }}>
          <Toolbar>
            <ScienceTwoToneIcon></ScienceTwoToneIcon>
            <Typography
              variant="h5"
              noWrap
              component="a"
              href="/"
              sx={{
                mr: 2,
                fontWeight: 200,
                fontFamily: 'roboto',
                color: 'white',
                letterSpacing: '.2rem',
                textDecoration: 'none',
              }}
            >
              LABREPORT
            </Typography>
            <Box sx={{ flexWrap: 'wrap', flexGrow: 1, display: 'flex' }}>
              {my_pages.map((page) => (
                <Button
                  key={my_pages}
                  sx={{ my: 2, color: 'whitesmoke', display: 'block', paddingRight: '20px' }}

                  href={`/${page}`}
                >
                  {page}
                </Button>
              ))}
            </Box>
            <Box sx={{ flexWrap: 'wrap', flexGrow: 1, display: 'flex' }}>
              {
                (contextUser.isEnable)? (null) : (
                  <>
                    <Button
                      sx={{ my: 2, color: 'whitesmoke', display: 'block', paddingRight: '15px' }}
                      href={`/login`}

                    >
                      Login
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                      sx={{ my: 2, color: 'whitesmoke', display: 'block', paddingRight: '15px' }}
                      href={`/SignUp`}
                    >
                      SignUp
                    </Button>
                  </>
                )
              }
              {
                // !(contextUser.authorities[0] === "ROLE_MASTER") ? (null) : (
                  !(contextUser.authorities[0] === "ROLE_MASTER" && contextUser.authorities != null) ? (null) : (
                  <>
                    <Button
                      sx={{ my: 2, color: 'tomato', display: 'block', paddingRight: '20px' }}
                      href={`/MASTER`}
                    >
                      MASTER
                    </Button>
                  </>
                )
              }
            </Box>
            <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
              <Tooltip title="Open my_settings">
                <IconButton onClick={handleOpenSettingsMenu} sx={{ p: 0 }}>
                  <Avatar alt="" src="" />
                </IconButton>
              </Tooltip>
              <Menu
                sx={{ mt: '55px' }}
                id="menu-appbar"
                anchorEl={anchorElUser}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'top',
                  horizontal: 'right',
                }}
                open={Boolean(anchorElUser)}
                onClose={handleCloseSettingsMenu}
              >
                {my_settings.map((setting) => (
                  <MenuItem key={setting} onClick={handleCloseSettingsMenu}>
                    <Typography textAlign="center">{setting}</Typography>
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Menu>
            </Box>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Login.js =>

```
export default function Login() {
  const [user,setUser] = useState({
    email: "error",
    password: 'error',
  })
  const { contextUser, logIn, logOut } = useContext(UserContext);


  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // event.preventDefault();
    // const data = new FormData(user.email,user.password);
   

    fetch('/auth/login', {//AuthRequest is Object
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body:  JSON.stringify([user.email,user.password])
    })
    .then(res => {//res={user:{k:v}, token:""}
      if (res.ok) return res.json();
      else alert("Giriş Başarısız");
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
    })
    // .then(res => logIn(res.user))
    .then(res =>logIn(res))
    .then(console.log(contextUser.user))
    .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs" sx={{ backgroundColor: 'yourBackgroundColor' }}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Box
          sx={{
            marginTop: 8,
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main' }}>
            <LockOutlinedIcon />
          </Avatar>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            Teknisyen Girişi
          </Typography>
          <Box noValidate sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
            {/* component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} */}
            <TextField
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              id="email"
              label="Email Adresi"
              name="email"
              autoComplete="email"
              autoFocus
              onChange = {(e) => setUser({...user, email: e.target.value})}
            />
            <TextField
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              name="password"
              label="Şifre"
              type="password"
              id="password"
              autoComplete="current-password"
              onChange = {(e) => setUser({...user, password: e.target.value})}
            />

            <Button
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              onClick={handleSubmit}
              sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
            >
              Giriş Yap
            </Button>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs>
                <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                  Şifreni hatırlamıyor musun?
                </Link>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <Link href={"/SignUp"} variant="body2">
                  {"Yeni misin?"}
                </Link>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        </Box>
        <Copyright sx={{ mt: 8, mb: 4 }} />
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Could it be wrong that navbar buttons use "href={`/${page}`}"? I think "context.js" was re-rendered between redirects. But I dont have idea for the solution.
Different suggestions that are permanent and can solve the problem radically are also very useful. What are the correct methods for session control?

Comment: Your context only persists in-memory. When you load a new page, everything is reset. You need to use React Router `<Link>` elements to avoid full page loads.

Comment: Oh yes. This saves the situation for now. I replaced the href with: component={Link} 
to={`/${page}`} Thanks for your suggestion.